# Getting values in string in Hive query

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have got a table in Hive, in which one of the columns is string. The values in that column are like "x=1,y=2,z=3". I need to write a query that adds the value of x in this column for all the rows. How do I extract the value of x and add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need a `UDF` for this transformation:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Description;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

class SplitColumn extends UDF {

  public Integer evaluate(Text input) {
    if(input == null) return null;
    String val=input.toString().split("=")[1];
    return Integer.parseInt(val);
  }
}
```

Now you can try this:

```
hive> ADD JAR target/hive-extensions-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
hive> CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION SplitColumn as 'com.example.SplitColumn';
hive> select sum(SplitColumn(mycolumnName)) from mytable;
```

P.S:  I have not tested this. But this should give a direction for you to proceed.